# PHP 7GB file download stops early between 3GB to 4.5GB

Tags: php, file, byte

I have a game I'm trying to release and it's size is 7GB. I'm using PHP to distribute it. The PHP script I've written can start the download without issue and I can use this same script for a much smaller zip and it downloads fine. I can also unzip the smaller file and extract it's contents without issue. However, when I attempt to download the larger file it seems to stop early anywhere between 3GB to 4.5GB. It's mostly random though most of the time it tends to stop at around the 4.3GB mark. Obviously, when I try to unzip the incomplete file it is corrupted and cannot be unzipped.

I can see the progress amount while the download is taking place in Google Chrome.

I have also tried using `while (!feof($handle))` instead of `while($size > $bytes_read)` with the same result. I have also tried disabling compression via .htaccess like so `SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary`. My php version is `7.3`.

I've been stuck on this for several days and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT with more info:**

1. Setting `ini_set('memory_limit',-1);` seemed to have no effect.
2. As a test, I set `usleep(1000000);` the download became much slower and the file stopped downloading at about 900MB. This makes me believe it should be a timeout issue, but then why does `ini_set('max_execution_time','0');` not solve this?
3. `var_dump(ini_get('safe_mode'));` is equal to `bool(false)`
4. **I believe the timeout is the Apachi timeout. I've timed the download several times and it stops at exactly 300 seconds which is the default Apachi timeout. I have a business account with GoDaddy and they are refusing to change the Apachi timeout.**

```
    ob_clean(); // Clear any previously written headers in the output buffer
    flush();
    ini_set('memory_limit','1G');
    ini_set('max_execution_time','0');
    $file = "builds/RoA.zip";
    $chunksize = 5 * (1024 * 1024); // different chunk sizes don't make a difference
    ob_start();
    set_time_limit(0);
    // ini_get(max_execution_time) returns 0
    
    if (is_file($file))
    {
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $basename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        $size = intval(sprintf("%u", filesize($file)));
        // http headers for zip downloads
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0", FALSE);
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        //header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: '.$size); // gives correct size to Google Chrome. Is able to see progress.
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$basename."\"");

        $handle = fopen($file, 'rb') or die("Couldn't get handle");
        
        $bytes_read = 0;
        while($size > $bytes_read)
        {
            set_time_limit(30);
            $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
            echo $buffer;
            $bytes_read+=$chunksize;
            
            ob_flush();
            flush();
        }

        fclose($handle); 
        
        ob_end_flush();
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the system's taking up more memory during the unzipping stage. I don't know for certain so I am only guessing by taking a stab at this. Did error reporting reveal anything? What is your system's max upload size reveal and anything related to that?

Comment: Try setting your limit to 0.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner oh it's not unzipping at all. It's just downloading an already zipped file. I'll try a 0 limit. 
Edit: 0 Limit just makes the file empty.

Comment: Ok. Yeah... I had a feeling that I sort of misunderstood the question, but was in the same ballpark as it were :-) Yet, the time limit thing could help which would do for any situation really.

Comment: I'm now trying -1 memory limit since that removes the limit completely. Stand back and watch as my server implodes

Comment: It stopped downloading at 4.08GB :(

Comment: Have you noticed the ```set_time_limit(30);``` inside your loop? It will limit the execution time to 30 seconds. Not 30 seconds for each loop iteration, but in the entire script.

Comment: I'm aware, every time you call `set_time_limit(30);` it resets the php timeout to 30 seconds. As a test, I removed that line and it still times out at 300 seconds.

Comment: Then your http server probably has a 300 second timeout. The default timeout of apache is exactly 300 seconds.

Comment: Godaddy will not update this as you may be using shared server so better to look for command to download via cli